# Space above DIV when appearing in text passages (tool tip)

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with white space appearing above div when inserted in between text. I have tried margin & padding things, but it hasn't worked out. I figure this must be a quite common issue, but I cannot seem to find an answer. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1hj4akqa/7/).

```css
div.appear {
  background-color:rgba(29,29,29,0.9);
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px ;
  z-index: 1000000;
 color: white;
 font-size:13px;
}
div.hover  {
  cursor:pointer; 
 color: #666;
  display: inline-block;
 
}
div.hover:hover div.appear {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<p>There is no exact definition on when a short story is too long, thus a<div class="hover">novella<div class="appear">A novella is a text that is longer than a short story, but not quite long enough to be a novel.</div></div> or a <div class="hover">novel<div class="appear">A novel is relatively long piece of fiction. What we often refer to as "a book".</div></div> on the other hand too short, becoming merely an <div class="hover">anecdote<div class="appear">an anecdote is a short tale</div></div>, to fit into the genre, but most short stories that we work with in the lessons are less than ten pages.
```

Comment: your jsfiddle link is not working. please modify it

Comment: @BirhanNega That's kind of OP's point, isn't it? :)

Comment: I'm new here. The link thing is confusing to me. But isn't the url working if you copy-paste it?

Comment: @micks88 Stackoverflow has built-in code snippets. I've made one from your Fiddle, as they're preferable to an external link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you use incorrect HTML tags.

- Don't use `<div>` inside `<p>`
- `<div>` are, by default, `display:block` thus they will try to expand all the way across the view.

Instead of `<div>` for your words and tooltips, use `<span>` that don't modify the layout :

```css
.appear {
  background-color: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.9);
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  z-index: 1000000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #666;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hover:hover .appear {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  There is no exact definition on when a short story is too long, thus a
  <span class="hover">
    novella
    <span class="appear">A novella is a text that is longer than a short story, but not quite long enough to be a novel.</span>
  </span>
  or a
  <span class="hover">
    novel
    <span class="appear">A novel is relatively long piece of fiction. What we often refer to as "a book".</span>
  </span>
  on the other hand too short, becoming merely an
  <span class="hover">
    anecdote
    <span class="appear">an anecdote is a short tale</span>
  </span>
  , to fit into the genre, but most short stories that we work with in the lessons are less than ten pages.
</p>
```

Comment: No worries :) Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put divs inside `<p>` tags. If you take a look at what you did with developer tools you will see that Chrome inserts a `</p>` tag after the word "thus", and that is where the padding/margin is coming from.

Just make all of your `<div>` tags `<span>` tags and that's it.

```
<p>There is no exact definition on when a short story is too long, 
thus a<span class="hover">novella<span class="appear">A novella is a 
text that is longer than a short story, but not quite long enough to be 
a novel.</span></span> or a <span class="hover">novel<span 
class="appear">A novel is relatively long piece of fiction. What we 
often refer to as "a book".</span></span> on the other hand too short, 
becoming merely an <span class="hover">anecdote<span class="appear">an 
anecdote is a short tale</span></span>, to fit into the genre, but most 
short stories that we work with in the lessons are less than ten pages.
```

Comment: If I do that the hover effect disappear. (even when deleting div from the name in css)

Comment: Ok. But I would suggest not to make tooltips this way anyway. There are much better solutions for something like that. Maybe try something like this: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-step-by-step-guide-to-making-pure-css-tooltips-3d5a3e237346